# How to loop through each user id?

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, user-registration

The functions that I am aware of:

```
WP_User
```

and

```
wp_get_current_user
```

seem to only get the user object of the current user. As an administrator, if I want to display certain profile information in a table from each user, how can I loop through the ids?

Can this be done with WP template tags or should I resort to SQL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)? You probably don't even need parameters for it, default behavior should be just what you're looking for.